# Indicator on indicator feature in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I found references about being able to select values from another indicator applied on chart as an input of type "source" to another indicator. I still see the option to apply indicator on indicator in GUI, however I cannot choose any other indicator in the Properties dropdown menu than the default ones. I read that there are limitations to what indicators we can select as an input, but I can't see even the basic ones as SMA or EMA, when applied to the chart.

Was this functionality limited in recent time? Or is there another way we can access data from other indicators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Basic or Pro plan, make sure you have not already used this feature because those plans can only have **1** "indicator on indicator" at any given time.

If you would like to add another script to your (user generated) script, make sure you have `input(type=input.source)`.

**Most importantly**, not all indicators can be calculated based on another indicator due to various technical difficulties. So, only ones that work are shown in the indicator list.

[Reference](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/new-feature-8211-apply-an-indicator-to-another-indicator-1844/).

Here, I just added SMA to RSI:

[image]